# Change Button function once clicked?

Tags: jquery

I made a button click that I want to open/close my side menu.
I did this:

```
$("#middleleftopenclose").click(function() {
     $("#middleleft").css("width", 0);
     $("#middleleftopenclose").css("opacity", 1);
     $("#middleright").css("margin-left", 15);
});
```

How would I go about making the same button click open the menu back as well?

Thanks

Comment: Create class for middleleft, middleleftopenclose and middleright and use .toogleClass() function

Comment: What are those CSS properties when the menu is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as a simple solution, you could have a boolean flag storing the current state of the sidebar and test against it every time the button is clicked.

```
var sidebarVisible = false;

$("#middleleftopenclose").click(function() {
  if (sidebarVisible){
    // close sidebar
  }else{
    // open sidebar
  }
  // toggle boolean flag each time button is clicked
  sidebarVisible = !sidebarVisible;
});
```

I see you are actually altering the css properties of the element within the function... Perhaps it would be better to create classes with the appropriate properties for each state and simply swap the classes when the button is clicked. [Meliborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520685/change-button-function-once-clicked#comment18509981_13520685) mentions this in a comment.

Comment: You are very welcome! I feel that adding and removing CSS classes might be a more elegant way to do this, But you should go with that ever method you feel most comfortable with. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery :visible selector to see if the side menu is visible or not. If it's is visible then hide, if not visible, then show.

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

```
$("#middleleftopenclose").click(function() {

     var visible = $("#SIDEMENU").is(":visible");

     if(!visible){

        // NOT VISIBLE - SO SHOW
        $("#middleleft").css("width", 0);
        $("#middleleftopenclose").css("opacity", 1);
        $("#middleright").css("margin-left", 15);

     }else{
        // VISIBLE - SO HIDE IT
        // WRITE YOUR CODE TO HIDE HERE
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add your CSS to classes, for example `.closedMenuLeft`, `.closedMenuLeftOpenClose`, `.closedMenuRight`, then toggle it on and off on click, like so:

```
$("#middleleftopenclose").click(function() {
    $("#middleleft").toggleClass("closedMenuLeft");
    $("#middleleftopenclose").toggleClass("closedMenuLeftOpenClose");
    $("#middleright").toggleClass("closedMenuRight");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though, `.toggleClass()` would be the perfect way to go. It lacks flexibility for more complex operations.

```
/* Aggregate in one CSS class, .active. */
.active #middleleft { width: 0; }
.active #middleleftopenclose { opacity: 1; }
.active #middleright { margin-left: 15; }
```

```
$("#middleleftopenclose").click(function() {
  $("#middle").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Considering `#middle` as the parent node of these elements.

Alternatively, you can make use of the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event. (Don't mistake with [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) animation.)

```
$("#middleleftopenclose").toggle(function() {
   // Show the element!
}, function(){
   // Hide the element!
});
```

These two functions will alternate execution between clicks. This is a built-in jQuery function.